# Why scrollTo(x,y) method of listview doesn't go to end of listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView Object` and use:

```
    Timer timer=new Timer();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void run() {
           lv1.scrollBy(0, counter_automatic);
           counter_automatic++;

                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 100);
```

code work correctly and don't get any Error! But I want `Scrolling` to go till end of listView!

My listView has `286 item`! but it goes only for 3 items and after 3 items scrolling continue but items `don't appear`!

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scrollBy()` scrolls by an amount of pixel, and not from item to item. [**The documentation of scrollBy()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollBy(int,%20int)) says:

> **public void scrollBy (int x, int y)**
>    Move the scrolled position of your view. This will cause a call to onScrollChanged(int, int, int,
>   int) and the view will be invalidated.
>
> **Parameters**
>   x - the amount of pixels to scroll by horizontally
>   y - the amount of pixels to scroll by vertically

So what you want to do is something like this:

```
listView.scrollTo(0, listView.getHeight());
```

Using `scrollTo()` instead of `scrollBy()` should be more reliable for your use-case.

But I guess the method you are actually looking for is `smoothScrollToPosition()`! Try something like this:

```
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getCount() - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `scrollBy` method takes pixels as parameters. I suppose you mix up of number of items with amount of pixels.

If you want to smooth scroll to a certain item use `smoothScrollToPosition` instead. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)

Comment: I don't want to use setSelction! I want use scrollTo for smooth scrolling

Answer (score 1):

The `scrollBy()` method is a member of the `View` class, and isn't going to work as you're expecting for a `ListView` because of how it handles its child `View`s. Depending on what exactly the desired behavior is, you probably want to use `smoothScrollToPosition(int position)` or `smoothScrollBy(int distance, int duration)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using scrollBy, try using setSelectionFromTop(int position, int pixelsFromTop). In your case, use counter_automatic as position and let the pixelsFromTop variable not change.